# Dynamic Widgets in Dashing

Tags: dashing

I'm new to using ruby and Coffee script but I have managed to get as far as displaying data within a single widget.

I am trying to think logically how would one go about creating a widget for each entry from a collection.

Does anyone know how to go about creating widgets after calling a service and getting a collection of data.

For example:

```
entries: [
    {
        name: "bob",
        age: 21
    },
    {
        name: "alex",
        age: 42
    },
    {
        name: "fred",
        age: 35
    }
]
```

I want to be able go through each of these and create a widget for each of these entries. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is easy enough. From any of the Ruby scripts you have in your jobs folder, you'll typically update a widget with a send_event call, like so:

```
send_event(widget.to_s, bus_info)
```

This will update the appropriate widget. A job, however, can make this call as much as is useful, so could update dozens of widgets in its run. You could just loop through your list and run send_event() for each item in your list. Play with it and if you get stuck, let me know and I can put together a bigger example, but hopefully you can use the above to get you going.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am looping through the objects but yet no luck with generating a new widget per entry/object. Could you explain a bit more with what you have already mentioned. I understand that a dash has the id which is linked to the send_event but not sure how to display the data into their own widgets on the dash.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more full example from our zendesk widget set.

```
def update_dashing(view, value)
  puts 'sending ' + view + ' : ' + value.to_s
  send_event('zendesk-' + view, current: value, status: 'normal',
                            service: 'Zendesk')
end

def update_zendesk(views)
  counts = zendesk_client.view_counts(ids: views, path: 'views/count_many')
  counts.all do |ct|
    next unless ct.fresh
    update_dashing(ct.view_id.to_s, ct.value.to_i)
  end
end
```

The zendesk_client.view_counts() function returns a list of `<view_id>:<count>` pairs that we then loop through.